# python, sklearn: 'dict' object is not callable using GridSearchCV and SVC

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use GridSearchCV to optimize the parameters for the classifier svm.SVC (both from sklearn).

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[2,3],[9,4],[4,5],[2,7],[1,0],[4,7],[2,9])
Y_train = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])
X_test = np.array([[2,4],[5,3],[7,1],[2,4],[6,4],[2,7],[9,2],[7,5],[1,6],[0,3]])
Y_test = np.array([1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0])
parameters = {'kernel':['rbf'],'C':np.linspace(10,100,10)}
clf1 = GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters, verbose = 10)
clf1.fit(X_train, Y_train)
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, clf1.predict(X_test))
bp = clf1.best_params_
```

The output shows it completing GridSearchCV, but then it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 479, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "I:\setup\Desktop\Stats\FinalProject.py", line 112, in <module>
clf1 = GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters, verbose = 10)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: The entire printout showing what went wrong, not just the last line.

Comment: When posting code, please make sure that others can run it, whenever this is possible. This means: include all your imports, create dummy data for uninitialized variables, etc... `SVC` appears to be a dict, but we don't know for sure, because we cannot see where it actually comes from.

Comment: Oh sorry, first timer.  Let me see if I can fix that for you.

Comment: I am stumbling over this line  `clf1.fit(X_train, Y_train)`, What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

When I am running the code you posted:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
Y_train = np.array([0,1,0])
X_test = np.array([[2,4],[5,3],[7,1]])
Y_test = np.array([1,0,0])
parameters = {'kernel':['rbf'],'C':np.linspace(10,100,10)}
clf1 = GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters, verbose = 10)
clf1.fit(X_train, Y_train)
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, clf1.predict(X_test))
bp = clf1.best_params_
```

I'm getting this error:

> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 447, in _validate_targets
>       % len(cls))
>   ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1

Since the train data consist of 3 samples, when the `GridSearchCV` break the data into 3 folds (BTW you can control this parameter, it is called [`cv`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html)).

e.g. -

```
fold1 = [1,2]  ,   label1 = 0
fold2 = [3,4]  ,   label2 = 1
fold3 = [5,6]  ,   label3 = 0
```

Now, in some iteration, it takes the first and the third folds to train on, and the second fold is used for validation. 
Please note that these training folds contains only 1 type of label! (the label 0) hence the error it prints.

If I create the data in this manner:

```
X, Y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                                n_informative=2, n_redundant=2, n_classes=2)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y,
                                                                         test_size =0.2)
```

It runs just fine.
I guess you have some other problem, but regarding the code you entered - this is the error it has.

Comment: @Lauren Clisby I referred to the code you inserted, but run it and update the `Traceback`

Comment: Sorry, that was just toy data.  I'll expand it a bit, so that is no longer the error, since that is not the original error anyway.

Comment: @LaurenClisby First of all, you forget a `]` in `X_train`. Secondly, this data (after your edit) runs with no errors! I suggest you try to run it before you paste here, so that you will be certain about the error. Please update!